# Vaadin set selected row of table

Tags: java, select, vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin: I need to set the selected row, after I update table content.
I have a Comboboxbutton containing different customers.
Additionally I have two tables, the first shows main categories and the secound shows subcategories.
Initially, no customer is selected, Main categories are shown, no subcategory is shown.

When I click on a category (lets say product for example!), sub-category table appers and shows sub-categories.
When I change the customer now from empty to a specific customer, both tables are filtered, BUT: The product-selection is lost. I need to set the selection to the one selected before.

I get the table content as an sql-container object from antoher class.

```
mainCatTable = new Table();
...
mainCatTable.setContainerDataSource(source.getMainCats());

//My Checkboxbutton
Combobox custBox = new ComboBox();

//Get the customers from the Database
custBox.setContainerDataSource(source.getCustomers());

custBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("Customers");
custBox.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
     public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent valueEvent) {  

//Here I need to store the old selection, before i update the mainCat table to a specific customer  
          mainCatTable.setContainerDataSource(source.getMainCats(currentCustomer));

//Here I need something to set the selected row to the previous value
          subCatTable.setContainerDataSource(source.getSubCats());
          }
});
```

The sql-container which the getMainCats method returns, is created like this:

```
FreeformQuery subcatExtractionQuery = new FreeformQuery("select customerName from customers", connectionPool);
return new SQLContainer(subcatExtractionQuery);
```

The problem is, t tried different ways, but it didn't work.
This was my try:
https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1819417/1819416
But they use an indexcontainer, but I don't.

Can anybody explain how to do this WITHOUT an index container?

Comment: what kind of controller is that "not indexed container"? Could you be somewhat more specific on this?

Comment: sorry, now i added information. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about to use value of the table to get/set "selected" row?

```
Object value = mainCatTable.getValue();    
mainCatTable.setContainerDataSource(source.getMainCats(currentCustomer));
mainCatTable.setValue(value);
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but wasn't successful.
THIS works - thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: Unfortunately this brings not the rigth selection always. Because it only takes the id. If the 3rd row is selected before the update, the thrid row is selected after the update. BUT: It's possible the the content changes (for ex: a new Maincat appers at the first row => The old one which was selected is now in the 4th and was in the 3rd before the update) so another mainCat is selected after the table update. So I would need something which can read the selected wird/String (thats no problem for me) and a SETVALUE which does not set the row via id, but set it to a specific String.